# Как сделать фон с эффектом слайдшоу?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Ситуация такова. Нужно сделать фон, как слайдшоу. Все бы ничего, я так и сделал, меняя у `<body>` свойство background. Но нужно сделать так, чтобы картинки фона, в моем случае их три, менялись автоматически, не исчезая, а слева направо, как на этом [сайте](http://enterosgel.ru//) (только чтобы это был фон сайта, а не отдельный слайдер на сайте).

Comment: Может быть? стоит менять свойство background-position?

Comment: Как будет выглядеть код, вы можете показать? Чтобы с таким эффектом менялись три фоновых картинки автоматически.

Comment: Сделал спасибо всем за интерес. Ответил бы на свой вопрос сам, да репутация не позволяет(

Comment: Здравствуйте, Нarley! Я сейчас пытаюсь сделать такой же эффект, и нигде не могу найти инфу как это осуществить... Не поделитесь своим умозаключением? Буду очень благодарна!

Comment: Здравствуйте, @yoursun. Я сделал так, после тега body, засунул картинки в div и этому div с параметрами position: absolute; width:100%; height:100%;
overflow:auto; z-index:-1;. Тогда создался искусственный фон. И затем при клике по кнопкам менял их. К сожалению того скрипта не осталось.  Но вы можете найти в интернете скрипт слайдера и соединить его с идеей выше.